# What is the main difference between clean and full_clean function in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

What is the main difference between clean and full_clean function in Django model ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean):

**Model.full_clean(***exclude=None, validate_unique=True***)**:

> This method calls `Model.clean_fields()`, `Model.clean()`, and
>   `Model.validate_unique()` (if `validate_unique` is `True`), in that order
>   and raises a `ValidationError` that has a `message_dict` attribute
>   containing errors from all three stages.

**Model.clean()**:

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to
>   modify attributes on your model if desired.

For more detailed explanation, have a look at the [Validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

They are not against each other. Usually you call **Model.full_clean()**, which calls **Model.clean()** for custom validation.
For example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models


class Brand(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    def clean(self):
        if self.title.isdigit():
            raise ValidationError("title must be meaningful not only digits")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

here are three steps involved in validating a model:

Validate the model fields - `Model.clean_fields()`

Validate the model as a whole - `Model.clean()`

Validate the field uniqueness - `Model.validate_unique()`

All three steps are performed when you call a model’s `full_clean()` method. for more information [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)